# Security of eval() with sanitized input

Tags: javascript, eval, sanitization

I want to use `eval()`to resolve simple equations and logical expressions, e.g. `12*(4+3)`.

How safe is client side eval when the input (possibly untrusted) gets sanitized and only allows digits, +-*/()<>|&! and the words 'true' and 'false'?

Available JS parsers for equations are too big and featureful for me. I threw one together myself, however it's a lot of lines of code compared to eval'ing and it's not yet perfect.

EDIT: So yeah, I guess what I'm specifically asking is can somebody execute malicious code with nothing but digits and +-*/()<>|&! ? (I guess 'true' and 'false' are harmless)

Comment: eval is not good by default, but if you don't have other options. regex will help you to sanitize input.

Comment: What do you need the words "true" and "false" for? How are you sanitizing it - could there be a bug in that? Show us your code :-)

Comment: and [Is using javascript eval() safe for simple calculations in inputs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14020780/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think either of those answers my specific question. The first is a general pondering about eval(), the second is answered with "It's safe because the user enters the input".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's completely safe, I don't think that `eval` is evil. Just use it with judice,
and double check your sanitize function.

Since you're not allowing unicode letters neither `_` or `$` to pass sanitization, and javascript identifier must contains letter, it won't be possible to pollute the global scope, not to call functions.

from [MDN page on identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals) :

> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode
>   letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX
>   Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

Remember to catch for exception thrown by `eval` calls, because it's always possible to enter wrong expression, e.g. `4><5`.

Also, be sure that you check for characters you allow, not for these that you deny, so that characters you didn't think about are denied by default.

Comment: Javascript identifier mustn't contain letter- it can be a bare _ symbol, for instance: var _ = 2;
In this case, the \"_\" character isn't allowed, but still- it's a correct identifier.

Comment: You're right, I edit my answer

Comment: That's a good thing...

Comment: To add to @JackL., almsot every character except for a few ones are acceptable variable names. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers. `var π = Math.PI;` works just fine.

Comment: This is why I suggest to whitelist allowed characters... anyway, I edit my answer to specify that any unicode letter could be used as an identifier.